# Kafka Spark Streaming: How to Produce and Consume a Record in the Last Batch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a Kafka Spark Job which is a daily batch job, which reads HDFS part files sequentially from a hadoop location and produce them sequentially.

In the last batch, i am picking up the last record in the batch and creating a new dataframe(df2) on top of it and rest of the records goes to another dataframe(df1).

I am producing df1 first and then producing df2, as i want the consumer(which is a streaming job) to consume df2 in the last batch among all the batches being sent from producer.
But it is not happening. In the consumer side, record in df2 is not being consumed in the last batch, instead it comes in the second last or third last batch, but not in the last batch.

Below is the sample code:

```
class XYZ{

create new Kafka Instance
.
                    ABC.getInstance(topic,<required Kafka Parameters>);
.
.
f(!(df2.toJavaRDD().isEmpty()) && !(df1.toJavaRDD().isEmpty())) {
                    calling produceDF method(df1, <required Kafka Parameters>);
                    calling produceDF method(df2, <required Kafka Parameters>);
                } 


    public void produceDF(Dataset<Row> df, Broadcast<ABC> abc>){
        df.foreachPartition(partitionOfRecords ->{
                    final ABC kafkaProducer = abc.value();
            while (partitionOfRecords.hasNext()) {
                Row row = partitionOfRecords.next();
                kafkaProducer.produceDF(<key>, <value>);
            }
            kafkaProducer.flush();
        });
}
}


class ABC implements Serializable{
        private transient KafkaProducer<String,String> kafkaProducer = null;
                private static ABC abcInstance;

                public static ABC getInstance(String topic, Map<String,Object> kafkaParams) {
        if(abcInstance==null){
            synchronized (ABC.class){
                if(abcInstance==null){
                    abcInstance = new ABC(topic,kafkaParams);
                }
            }
        }
        return abcInstance;
    }
    
public void produceDF(String key,String val) {
        if( null==kafkaProducer) {
            kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(<Kafka Parameters>);
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    kafkaProducer.close();
                }
            });

        }
        if(key!=null) {
    kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, key, val), new ProducerCallback(key, val));
}
        public void flush(){
        if(null!=kafkaProducer)
            kafkaProducer.flush();
    }
}
}
```

Please advise on what approach i need to follow to consume df2 in the last batch

Comment: while producing you know which is first batch,second batch & last batch .. add one flag while producing.. & while consuming try filter records on that flag..

Comment: @Srinivas Yes as i have mentioned above, df2 has a flag to identify as the last record, but the problem is df2 is not consumed as the last batch or you can say it does not fall in the last batch on consumer side, it always arrives before the last batch arrives. So how can i make sure that it arrives in the last batch only on consumer side